# Is there any cost for using the SAP HANA Client ODBC?

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, hana

I want to connect my reporting services with the SAP HANA database. But I need to know if using this ODBC involves any cost.

Comment: Look like you can just download it.. have a look at this -> https://help.sap.com/viewer/004ffbab33be483389191adb5663ac96/1.09.0.0/en-US/63ee40091a1847b886e3bcfe71ecb91a.html

Answer (score 2):

You can download the SAP HANA Client package (incl. ODBC driver) on the [SAP Development Tools](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools) site at no cost. The download is provided under the terms of the [SAP Developer License Agreement](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/developer-license-3_1.txt), which you should carefully check for applicable usage restrictions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll read all about it.